# Novel about an alien hunting another alien. Puts a dome over a city

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book few years ago and really enjoyed it but can't remember the name. I thought it was slither but can't find the right one. Was about an alien hunting for a peaceful alien on Earth and it puts a dome over the city and it goes from there.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be *[Stinger](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stinger-Robert-R-McCammon-ebook/dp/B005T54I4K)* by Robert R. McCammon?

> When Stinger, the monstrous alien bounty hunter, arrives, it’s with a
>   destructive fury and a devious plan to find Daufin—by entombing the
>   residents in an impenetrable and inescapable dome. A relentless
>   killing machine, Stinger has an infinite capacity for death and
>   destruction. And over the next twenty-four hours, this town is going
>   to bleed and burn. Now, the few remaining survivors must come together
>   to protect Daufin, themselves, and the world beyond from total
>   annihilation.

[image]